# Volley initializing error in DiskBaseChacke

Tags: android, android-volley

Below three line of code for volley android i am executing but i am getting a outofmemory error.

why is outofmemory is showing. what is the problem in this code.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);

        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

---

```
05-08 21:03:00.196: E/dalvikvm-heap(3800): Out of memory on a 536870928-byte allocation.
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800): "Thread-4690" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42c62c40 self=0x40000948
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   | sysTid=3816 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1106467000
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   | state=R schedstat=( 35549043 20857416 40 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=0
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:~569)
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:158)
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:546)
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
05-08 21:03:00.196: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
05-08 21:03:00.201: I/dalvikvm(3800):   at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
05-08 21:03:00.201: W/dalvikvm(3800): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42220700)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4690
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:569)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:158)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:546)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
05-08 21:03:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(3800):     at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

I have to initialize it in Application class while start the application. And the issue is fixed.

Comment: you sure? I still have this issue, can you post your application class?